# OpenCV XML Classifier

Tags: xml, opencv, cascade-classifier

I'm trying to build a Traffic Sign Recognition application using OpenCV but I don't know how to start.

I have read about this and I found that I need to implement a Cascade Object Detector and train it using thousand of positive and negatives images to generate a XML Classifier file ...

Exists another way to do that?

Where can I find a XML Classifier file already trained?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your description, you are planning to use the machine learning method for traffic sign recognition.
However, there are more things should be known before that.

Object recognition(Ok, here the object is Sign especially), can be divided into two main parts： Detection and Recognition.
For the detection part you may need the color threshold and polygon detection to separate the sign from the complex environment.(Which has so less relationship with the positive or negative training data.)

And for the recognition part, Machine learning is also just one option.
As far as I know, you can use sift or SURF for this part. And there are some papers about that. If you decided to use the training data for recognition, please post a question then.

All in all, please read some related papers from google.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm decided to use the training data for recognition. Is possible to find XML files already trained to recognition step? Detection step is already done.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenCV` bundle contains some classifier files for face, eye, nose and body detection. You will find it in the installer package. But for your custom object you need to build your own classifiers.

Check this : [OpenCV Train Cascade](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html)